# Kotlin - Handling Names From EditText

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I have two EditTexts which take in a input type of `android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"`

The user will presumably input their name ("John Doe"), and this will be saved unto Firestore.

I believe that `textPersonName|textCapWords` will handle capitalizing the first characters in their names, however, I want to handle a case in which a user puts one too many empty spaces between their name ("John    Doe").

I've thought of doing something like this:

```
val splitCMName = caseManager.split(" ")

    val joinedCMName = splitCMName.joinToString {
        splitCMName[0] + " " + splitCMName[splitCMName.lastIndex]

    })
```

However, I'm wondering how to implement this in a more Kotlin/Android Studio manner, if there is one. I think my approach to this might be too Pythonic.

I would highly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using regular expressions to replace all whitespace with a single space character?

```
val normalized = caseManager.replace(Regex("\\s+"), " ")
```

Comment: Ben! Thank you so much! This gave me the output I was looking for.